# Reset form values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to reset the values of a form that had already been used, using javascript.  I had tried to make a function that would set the values to an "empty string" (not sure if that's what it's called in this case, but '') and then to their default values, but this didn't work.  And I had tried form reset, but that seemed to delete my form.  I would be okay with restoring default values except I couldn't figure out how to set the radio button to NULL or nothing.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't `form.reset()` do what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure if I had used it incorrectly, but my form had disappeared when I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<input type="reset" />`*<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input)</sup>*, which will render a button that resets the form back to the state it was in when it was loaded.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/zEYEa/embedded/result/